# How to resolve boto3 client error? service_nake

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

can't connect to s3 and ses using boto3

```
client = boto3.client(
        service_nake = "s3",
        region_name = "us-east-1",
        aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY
    )
```

got this error when try to access s3 from boto when i try to access s3 and ses

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-334ac10efd3e> in <module>
----> 1 client = boto3.client(
      2         service_nake = "s3",
      3 #         region_name = "us-east-1",
      4         aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
      5         aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_KEY

~\Desktop\poc\goldform\venv\lib\site-packages\boto3\__init__.py in client(*args, **kwargs)
     91     See :py:meth:`boto3.session.Session.client`.
     92     """
---> 93     return _get_default_session().client(*args, **kwargs)
     94 
     95 

TypeError: client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_nake'
```

Comment: Hi. I've noticed that you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it also reduced duplicates and makes your questions more likely to be answered.

Comment: You should ***really*** learn to read and interpret error messages. The error message is VERY clear and it should be obvious after a few seconds what the problem / error is.

Answer (score 3):

Typo! `service_nake` should be `service_name`

Comment: Yes you are right. My Mistake.

Comment: this is the error i got, update the above content with error code.
TypeError: client() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service_nake'

Comment: @mageshwaran Your error is a misspelling, as shown above.